# Double recursive call

Tags: python, recursion, higher-order-functions

```
 def print_numbers(n, k):  
 """Print all numbers that (A) can be formed from the digits  of `n` in reverse
order and (B) are multiples of `k`.
  Args:  n (int): The number that results must use digits from. 
 k (int): The number that results must be multiples of.    
  >>> print_numbers(97531, 5) 
     135 
     15
     35"""
   def inner(n,s):
     if n == 0:
        if s % k == 0 and s > 0:
             print(s)
     else:
          inner(n // 10, s*10 + n % 10) #first
          inner(n // 10, s) #second
   inner(n,0)
```

I have some troubles with understanding the part of the recursive calls. As I understand the second recursive call can not be called before the first reached the phase when it should give the return value. However, the what the first call do (in the example):
 It gives inner(9753,1),inner(975,13),inner(97,135),inner(9,1357),inner(0,13579)

As then n is equal to 0 the s(13579) is not divisible by k(5) therefore it does not print anything. Moreover, the return value is None by the way function is constructed. So, when inner(0,13579) phase is achieved the second recursive call must start working, however it will constantly try 0 // 10 and won't proceed.

This is my understanding. Can you point out where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple issues. 
First, think of recursion as a hierarchy of stacks.

> However, the what the first call do (in the example): It gives
>   inner(9753,1),inner(975,13),inner(97,135),inner(9,1357),inner(0,13579)

One issue here is that the first call doesn't get locked onto only executing that one line. each call is spawning two new calls in the else block. More on this in a sec.

> So, when inner(0,13579) phase is achieved the second recursive call
>   must start working, however it will constantly try 0 // 10 and won't
>   proceed.

This is flawed. Why must the value of "n" be zero for this call? if you recall, the first instance of this call was during an else block that was hit for n = 97531.

It does not matter that the statement above it dove into a recursion, because those variables and values exist at a lower stack compared to the stack of relevance for this statement.

An easier way is to consider each stack separately.

```
stack 1: n = 97531
else: #n//10 = 9753
    child1 (9753,1)
    child2 (9753,0)
            stack2 - child1:
            else: #n//10 = 975
                child11 (975,13)
                child12 (975,1)
            stack2 - child2:
            else: #n//10 = 975
                child21 (975, 3)
                child22 (975, 0) #and so on.
```

Each level of hierarchy has their variables determined, and will spawn recursive functions that belong to a lower hierarchy until you hit the base case separately for each "branch/spawn" so to speak.

**To Summarise**
You can boil it down to a hierarchy of stacks. At that point, this function becomes simple to digest.
Essentially, for each digit while the number is greater than zero, take out the last digit, and make two choices. Use the last digit, and discard the last digit. Do this over and over, and you end up considering all possible numbers that can be formed in reverse order, by using or discarding digits.